# How to move a feature from "Manage Site Features" to "Site Collection Features"

Tags: web-part, feature, feature-activation, feature-scope

I have developed many custom web parts. These web part's features have always been placed in the Site Collection Features page under Site Collection Administration. For some reason a new web part i made feature is in Manage Site Features. I did not change anything when i created this new Web Part.

Is there a way for me to move the feature from Manage Site Features to Site Collection Features?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the feature scope in Visual Studios be "Site" instead of "Web".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231541.aspx